# the original reference of upper-bounded projective resolution?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, derived-categories

We know that upper-bounded complexes have upper-bounded projective resolution, and lower-bounded complexes have lower-bounded injective resolution. I want to know the original reference which show this result? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the earliest reference, but let me mention

- Jean-Louis Verdier, *Catégories dérivées, Etat 0*, 1963.

It can be found in SGA 4½, published in 1976 (LNM, volume 569).

By applying Proposition I.6.4 of this work to the homotopy category $K^+(\mathcal{A})$ of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ with enough injectives, one obtains that for every complex $C$, there is a complex, bounded below, of injective objects $I(C)$ and a quasi-isomorphism $C\to I(C)$.  Dually, one obtains the result for complexes of projective objects as well.